# MySQL Case statement with multiple AND OR cannot be nested

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to group the iOs versions into

```
11,12,13,14,14.5 and above
```

but having problem with the `AND OR` part of the `CASE` statement where the 14. versions supposed to be grouped.
I have tried to add brackets but then the query cannot be executed. this way it skips the
`OR` part of the query.

-- % of iOS Users per OS Version

```
With os_split ("device_name", "number_of_devices")
AS
(
    -- % of Mobile Device Per User
 select 
        CASE
            WHEN "os_version" ilike '11%' THEN 'iOS 11'
            WHEN "os_version" ilike '12%' THEN 'iOS 12'
            WHEN "os_version" ilike '13%' THEN 'iOS 13'
            WHEN "os_version" like '14' 
            OR "os_version" ilike '14.0%' 
            OR "os_version" ilike '14.1%'
            OR "os_version" ilike '14.2%'
            OR "os_version" ilike '14.3%' THEN 'iOS 14'
            WHEN "os_version" ilike '14.5%' THEN 'iOS 14.5'
            ELSE "os_version"
            END
            AS "os_version",
        --"os_version",
        count("os_version") as "number_of_occurences"
 FROM temp_db.data_lake.adjust_csv_imports
 WHERE TRUE
 AND "platform" = 'mobile_app'
 AND "event_name" = 'onboarding_completed'
 AND "os_name" = 'ios'
    group by 1
   HAVING count("os_version") > 0
  
 )
 SELECT 
        a1."device_name", 
        a1."number_of_devices",
        round(a1."number_of_devices"/(SELECT SUM("number_of_devices") FROM os_split),2) Pct_To_Total
FROM os_split a1,os_split a2
    WHERE TRUE
    AND a1."number_of_devices" <= a2."number_of_devices" 
    OR (a1."number_of_devices"= a2."number_of_devices" 
        AND a1."device_name" = a2."device_name")
        group by 
        a1."number_of_devices", 
        a1."device_name"
        order by 
        a1."number_of_devices" desc, 
        a1."device_name" desc
;
```

What I get:

| device_name | number_of_devices | PCT_TO_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14.4.2 | 6816 | 0.60 |
| iOS 14.5 | 1269 | 0.11 |
| 14.6 | 852 | 0.08 |
| 14.4.1 | 835 | 0.07 |
| iOS 14 | 551 | 0.05 |
| 14.4 | 339 | 0.03 |
| 14.4.0 | 2744 | 0.02 |
| iOS 13 | 2388 | 0.02 |
| iOS 12 | 1305 | 0.01 |
| 14.7 | 84 | 0.00 |
| 14.6.0 | 38 | 0.00 |
| 15.0 | 32 | 0.00 |
| iOS 11 | 23 | 0.00. |

What I would like to get:

| device_name | number_of_devices | PCT_TO_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iOS 14.5 | 1200 | 0.11 |
| iOS 14.6+ | 852 | 0.08 |
| iOS 14 | 551 | 0.05 |
| iOS 13 | 2388 | 0.02 |
| iOS 12 | 1305 | 0.01 |
| iOS 11 | 23 | 0.00. |

Comment: Can you share some sample data, the result you're getting for it and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: hey! I have updated the original post, could you have a look, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of the OR within the CASE statement which was incorrect, I just used IN()
This is definitely not the most efficient way of doing this because with each and every new iOS version I have to update the query but it does the job for now.

```
WITH os_split (
    "ios_version",
    "number_of_users"
) AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN "os_version" ILIKE '11%' THEN
            'iOS 11'
        WHEN "os_version" ILIKE '12%' THEN
            'iOS 12'
        WHEN "os_version" ILIKE '13%' THEN
            'iOS 13'
        WHEN "os_version" in('14',
            '14.4',
            '14.4.0',
            '14.1.1',
            '14.2',
            '14.4.2',
            '14.3',
            '14.4.1',
            '14.3.0') THEN
            'iOS 14'
        WHEN "os_version" ILIKE '14.5%' THEN
            'iOS 14.5'
        ELSE
            'iOS 14.6+'
        END AS "os_version",
        --"os_version",
        count("os_version") AS "number_of_occurences"
    FROM
        temp_db.data_lake.adjust_csv_imports
    WHERE
        TRUE
        AND "platform" = 'mobile_app'
        AND "event_name" = 'onboarding_completed'
        AND "os_name" = 'ios'
    GROUP BY
        1
    HAVING
        count("os_version") > 0
)
SELECT
    "ios_version",
    "number_of_users",
    round("number_of_users" / (
            SELECT
                SUM("number_of_users")
                FROM os_split), 3) Pct_To_Total
FROM
    os_split
GROUP BY
    "number_of_users",
    "ios_version"
HAVING
    Pct_To_Total > 0
ORDER BY
    "number_of_users" DESC,
    "ios_version" DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `REGEXP` inside your `CASE` expression to detect the various 14.x% values.

```
CASE
    WHEN os_version LIKE '11%' THEN 'iOS 11'
    WHEN os_version LIKE '12%' THEN 'iOS 12'
    WHEN os_version LIKE '13%' THEN 'iOS 13'
    WHEN os_version REGEXP '^14\.[0-3]%' THEN 'iOS 14'
    WHEN os_version LIKE '14.5%' THEN 'iOS 14.5'
    ELSE os_version
END
```

It isn't valid syntax to use `OR` inside a `CASE` expression as you are trying to do in your question.

Comment: thanks for your input! Unfortunately this produces multiple 14. rows.

device_name number_of_devices PCT_TO_TOTAL
14.4.2 68167 0.60
iOS 14.5 12690 0.11
14.6 8524 0.08
14.4.1 8353 0.07
14.4 3392 0.03
14.4.0 2744 0.02
iOS 13 2388 0.02
iOS 12 1305 0.01
14.3 1271 0.01
14.2 962 0.01
14 634 0.01
14.3.0 615 0.01
14.0.1 535 0.00
14.2.0 406 0.00
14.1 363 0.00
14.0 254 0.00
14.2.1 200 0.00
14.1.0 155 0.00
14.0.0 115 0.00
14.7 84 0.00
14.6.0 38 0.00
15.0 32 0.00
iOS 11 23 0.00

Comment: I focused on the `CASE` expression itself, the larger query being not completely clear to me.  It sounds like perhaps you need to also `GROUP BY` this `CASE` expression to remove the duplicate/extra rows you don't want.

Comment: could you explain how this should be done, please? I have also updated the original post to show what I get as my query result and what I am aiming for.

Comment: I can't give an exact answer without the starting and ending data (which you have not shown above).  Basically, you want to group by the case expression in my answer, and take counts using that group.

Comment: hey Tim! You can find the starting data to my original comment. Could you have a look, please?